# How to replace Controller Variables with javascript variables on visual force page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I've an apex page that is using controller variables for rendering data via apex tags on visualforce page, But this variable increases view state size so I want to replace it with javascript variable and make the controller variable transient.

My code snippet is as following :

```
<apex:repeat value="{!allObjectPermissionMap[st.sourceTargetId]}" var="sol">
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!sol}" var="so">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="objPerm--{!st.sourceTargetId}" onchange="toggleItem('objPerm', 'objPerm--{!st.sourceTargetId}');" value="{!so.isSelected}" disabled="{!so.targetObjPermissions = null}"></apex:inputCheckbox></td>
                                        <td>{!so.objName}</td>
                                        <td><c:profilepermissionviewer OK="{!so.sourceObjPermissions.allowRead}"/></td>
                                        <td><c:profilepermissionviewer OK="{!so.sourceObjPermissions.allowCreate}"/></td>   
                                        <td><c:profilepermissionviewer OK="{!so.sourceObjPermissions.allowEdit}"/></td>
                                        <td><c:profilepermissionviewer OK="{!so.sourceObjPermissions.allowDelete}"/></td>
                                        <td><c:profilepermissionviewer OK="{!so.sourceObjPermissions.viewAllRecords}"/></td>
                                        <td><c:profilepermissionviewer OK="{!so.sourceObjPermissions.modifyAllRecords}"/></td>

                                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!so.targetObjPermissions != null}">
                                            <td><c:profilepermissionviewer OK="{!so.targetObjPermissions.allowRead}"/></td>
                                            <td><c:profilepermissionviewer OK="{!so.targetObjPermissions.allowCreate}"/></td>   
                                            <td><c:profilepermissionviewer OK="{!so.targetObjPermissions.allowEdit}"/></td>
                                            <td><c:profilepermissionviewer OK="{!so.targetObjPermissions.allowDelete}"/></td>
                                            <td><c:profilepermissionviewer OK="{!so.targetObjPermissions.viewAllRecords}"/></td>
                                            <td><c:profilepermissionviewer OK="{!so.targetObjPermissions.modifyAllRecords}"/></td>
                                        </apex:outputPanel>

                                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!so.targetObjPermissions = null}">
                                            <td><label>{!$Label.NA}</label></td>
                                            <td><label>{!$Label.NA}</label></td>
                                            <td><label>{!$Label.NA}</label></td>
                                            <td><label>{!$Label.NA}</label></td>
                                            <td><label>{!$Label.NA}</label></td>
                                            <td><label>{!$Label.NA}</label></td>
                                        </apex:outputPanel>
                                    </tr>   
                                </apex:repeat>
```

All I want to do is to replace 'allObjectPermissionMap' variable with javascript variable and rest of the code remains same. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to serialize the `Map` and retrieve it in Javascript like this:

In your controller define a getter that retrieves the `Map` as a JSON string:

```
public transient Map <Id, SomeSObject> sObjectMap     {get;set;}
public transient String                sObjectJSON    {get{return JSON.serialize(sObjectMap);}}
```

To access the Map in Javascript, you can instantiate as the page loads like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var previousOnload = window.onload;        
    window.onload = function() { 
        if (previousOnload) { 
        previousOnload();
    }
    //your object can be accessed using array or object dot notation in Javascript now
    var obj = JSON.parse('{!sObjectJSON}');
  }               
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Actually  what I was trying to ask is How can I use this javascript map in vf page ?
I want to use this javascript map instead of 'allObjectPermissionMap' on vf page. Is it possible ?